# Codeigniter : Filename didn't appear on database

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just learn to save image data to database, those are filename and path. The path is appear on database, but not with filename. Whats the problem?

This is the controller,

```
function do_upload() {
    $config['upload_path']='./uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '100';
    $config['max_width'] = '1024';
    $config['max_height'] = '768';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload_model->upload($config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload()){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

        $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
    } else {
        $data  = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

        $this->load->view('upload_success', $data);
    }
}
```

and the model

```
    function upload ($config) {
    $config = $this->upload->data();
    $upload_data = array(
        'path' => $config['full_path'],
        'nama_foto' => $config['file_name']
    );

    $this->db->insert('tb_picture', $upload_data);
}
```

and the table
[image]

what should i do?

thank you before.

Comment: Try doing a `var_dump($config)` to check what's actually in that array.

Comment: @Nana Puspita please read your code line by line in order, does your `$config` variable have property `[full_path]` ? well, I guess __no__ because you insert it in to database **before** actual file upload happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before reading this please try it again yourself, or try any kind of viedotutorial that is on the web http://net.tutsplus.com/sessions/codeigniter-from-scratch/

**controller** function should look like this

```
function do_upload()
    {
        $config['upload_path']='./uploads/'; //needs to set uploads folder CHMOD 0644
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '100';
        $config['max_width'] = '1024';
        $config['max_height'] = '768';

        $config['overwrite']  = FALSE;
        $config['remove_spaces']  = TRUE;

        $field_name = "userfile"; //name tag in our HTML form in case you want to change it

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload($field_name)) //upload happens
        {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
        }    
        else
        {
             //succesful upload get data from upload and use them with our model
             $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
             $this->upload_model->upload($upload_data);
        }
    }
```

**model** function

```
function upload ($data) {

    if (empty($data) || $data === FALSE) return FALSE;

    $insert_data = array(
        'path' => $data['full_path'],
        'nama_foto' => $data['file_name']
    );

   $this->db->insert('tb_picture', $insert_data);

   return $this->db->insert_id(); //returns last inserted ID
}
```

Please note that your model was totaly "wrong" you used upload function in it, try to pass `data` only to it so model can process it.

Comment: thanks for your answer.. It's totally true. and the link, really interested. thank you so much.